# VBA: Error handling only works once in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, error-handling

My code checks the existence of a list of files from their paths listed in an Excel table. Existing files are valued 1 in the table and non-existing files are valued 0.

The error handler works for the first error, continues the loop and carries on to verify right until it hits the second error after which it displays the error message and halts the macro.

I have tried different iterations of including resume and resume next as suggested elsewhere which either results in 'false positives' as the code resumes the 'then' code under the failed if-statement and values them as 1 (exists) or gets stuck in an infinite loop at the second error.

```
Sub File_Check()
    Dim Filename, Trade_day, Today, lastmodified As String
    Dim MasterTable As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer

    Today = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")
    Trade_day = Range("Trade_day_file")

Set MasterTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").ListObjects("MasterTable")


MasterTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange = 0

For i = 1 To MasterTable.ListRows.Count


    On Error GoTo Does_Not_Exist


    'Check date in filename
        Filename = VBA.Dir(MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value & Trade_day & MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Value)

        If Filename <> vbNullString Then

            MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 1) = 1

    'Check file creation date instead
        ElseIf Format(FileDateTime(MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value & MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Value), "DD-MM-YYYY") = Today Then
            MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 1) = 1

        End If


    GoTo Skip_Err_Handler



Does_Not_Exist:

         MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 1) = 0
         Err.Clear


Skip_Err_Handler:

Next i
```

Comment: You don't need `GoTo Skip_Error_Handler`.  Just put `Next i` in its place.  Then you will need a resume or exit sub to exit the error handler.

Comment: Within `Does_Not_Exist` you should end with `resume next` so that it continues through to the next line in your loop (After the error causing line) and doesn't terminate.

Comment: SJR i have tried this, the code functions well as VBA.dir returns a nullstring on error, but the FileDateTime returns the error ' file does not exist' when it in fact, does not exist.  @Darrel H I just tried this (having 'Next i' above the error handler and removing skip_err_handler) this results in the sub ending after the first error.

Comment: @Freeflow i have option explicit, just didnt include in the post :)  VB.Dir works perfectly as it does not return an error message but a vbnullstring when a file does not exist. The error message occurs when the FileDateTime function is applied to a non-existing file for the second time in the loop. I generally agree regarding the error handling, but i do not know of a method to determin a files creation date and time using the fso method.

Comment: When you have created your scripting.filesystemobject you use the get file method as in <fsoreference>.GetFIle(<Filename>).DateCreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, add 'Resume Skip_Err_Handler' and it works like a charm. It assigns the value 1 to paths that exist, and 0 to paths that do not exist.
Code attached for others with the same loop error-handling issue:

```
Sub File_Check()
    Dim Filename, Trade_day, Today, lastmodified As String
    Dim MasterTable As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer

    Today = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")
    Trade_day = Range("Trade_day_file")

Set MasterTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").ListObjects("MasterTable")


MasterTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange = 0

For i = 1 To MasterTable.ListRows.Count


    On Error GoTo Does_Not_Exist


    'Check date in filename
        Filename = VBA.Dir(MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value & Trade_day & MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Value)

        If Filename <> vbNullString Then

            MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 1) = 1

    'Check file creation date instead
        ElseIf Format(FileDateTime(MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value & MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Value), "DD-MM-YYYY") = Today Then
            MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 1) = 1

        End If


    GoTo Skip_Err_Handler


Does_Not_Exist:

         MasterTable.DataBodyRange(i, 1) = 0
         Err.Clear
         Resume Skip_Err_Handler


Skip_Err_Handler:

Next i

End Sub
```